# Retrieve Custom Field in ParseUser

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve a "location" field that I added when a user first makes their account. The location field is just another field like "username" or "email". I know you can use the following way to get one field:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereEqualTo("playerEmail", "dstemkoski@example.com");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
      Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
      Log.d("score", "Retrieved the object.");
    }
  }
});
```

The problem with the way above is that I do not know what the location will be because it is different for each user and there are 50 different locations, so I cannot use the whereEqualTo method. I just need the information from the location field of my ParseUsers and then be able to display it in a toast or a listview.

UPDATE:

Here is my listview and adapter in the `onResume` method:

```
mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser
            .getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = mFriendsRelation.getQuery();
    query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            if (e == null) {
                mFriends = friends;
                String[] usernames = new String[mFriends.size()];
                int i = 0;
                for (ParseUser user : mFriends) {
                    usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                    i++;
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getListView().getContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usernames);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                // log error
                // left out to cut out code length
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is what I tried: `final Object o = getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
        //String user = (String) o;
        ParseUser user = (ParseUser) o;
        String loc = (String) user.get("location");
        Toast.makeText(Friends.this,"Location is " + loc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

and get the error `cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseUser` for the line `ParseUser user = (ParseUser) o;`

Comment: if you just want the location of the user owning the device you can do `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("location")`. Otherwise, can you try and explain more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: `whereEqualTo` is not for getting the fields. It is a constraint for your query. For example in your case it means "Give me the users with email dstemkoski@example.com". It returns these users with all of their fields and then you can access the field you want `object.getString("location");` Moreover, you can also restrict the query to return selected fields `query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("playerEmail", "location"));`

Comment: @cYrixmorten no I am not trying to get the user that is owning the device, I am trying to get the friends of that user and display a location field from that friend.

@knshn I have tried the following in my `onListItemClick` method. Please look in the op for what i tried.

Comment: @Kooky_Lukey Ok, so clearly the objects within your list is not ParseUser objects. Can you share how you construct your ListView, what does you Adapter for the List look like?

Comment: Added the listview and adapter. Thanks for all the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: a _username_ is not a `ParseUser` object. you can create objects if you have the `objectId` with `createWithoutData`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options, most refer to your `onListItemClick` function: 
include the username as a string (as that's what you're using to build) to find the user details you need (as new query), reference the location that belongs to that user (`String[] locations = new String[mFriends.size()];`), or build your array/display your list with both fields (username *and* location)

Referencing the location would be preferred as it avoids another query.

Get details on click using second query - make sure your usernames are unique and use the original "get a field" query you posted - see 
https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-querying and https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html

see also: https://parse.com/questions/android-how-to-access-fields-when-using-findinbackground

```
private void findUserLocation(String username) { 
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseQuery.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("username", username);
    ...
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
            ...
            //stores locations for all users that match the username
            String[] locations = new String[users.size()];
            for (ParseUser user : users) {
                locations[i] = user.getString("location");
                i++;
            }
            ...
```

When referencing the location - you can store this in your original  `for` loop with e.g. `locations[i] = user.get("location");` and then retrieve it in your on click function `String loc = locations[position];`

In all cases, you'll want to check if the `location` field is defined/not empty when storing and/or before displaying it (depending on your application)